# Detecting when certain bootstrap glyphicons are present on a page with Selenium IDE

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-ide

I have some registration fields, and if the name field is empty and the submit button is clicked, I display a glyphicon at the end of the input field box with:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
```

With Selenium IDE, how do I detect only when that glyphicon is showed on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

VerifyElementPresent should work here.

Comment: I tried VerifyElementPresent, but it always detects the glyphicon whether or not it's displayed. I think it's because bootstrap merely makes the glyph invisible when it's not being shown? The span is greyed out just like the other warning codes i show when, for example the proper email condition isn't met.

Comment: got it working by switching the html to a bootstrap error div and checking for that error div and the field name.